# UITableView not dismissing after tapping on textfield

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, swift5

I have a text field which on click will open a table view. The problem is that I am not able to dismiss the table view after the first click.

```
lazy var leaveType1: UITextField = {
    let leaveType1 = UITextField()
    leaveType1.isEnabled = false
    let labelTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:#selector(self.empLeaveTypePressed))
    labelTapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    leaveType1.addGestureRecognizer(labelTapGesture)
    return leaveType1
}()
    
@objc func empLeaveTypePressed(_sender: Any){
    empLeaveTypeTable.isHidden = false
    empLeaveTypeTable.endEditing(true)
}
```

As you can see in image below, the user should be able to select the options and then tap the text field in order to dismiss the table view:

[image: Output image]

Comment: Describe your question please

Comment: i have a textfield , which on click will open a tableview
the problem is that i am not able to dismiss the tableview after the first click

Comment: you can add a done button on top of your tableview and hide tableview inside action of that done button, or you can do it inside main views tap-gesture recogniser.

Comment: as u can see in attached image, the user should be able to select the options and then tap the textfield in order to dismiss the tableview

Comment: try this `empLeaveTypeTable.isHidden = !empLeaveTypeTable.isHidden`

Comment: Welcome @Neil Johnson